# Les panneaux de signalisation "ARRÊT" au Québec sont-ils corrects?

Tags: usage, régionalismes, québec

En France et bien sûr en anglais, le signe équivalent de "ARRÊT" est "STOP".  Il est destiné à être un impératif; une commande.  Donc n'est-ce pas l'équivalent français "ARRÊTEZ" l'impératif, et pas "ARRÊT" le nom ?  Est-ce donc une erreur de traduction au Québec pour leur panneaux de signalisation ?  J'interprète "ARRÊT" comme "voilà un arrêt, vous voyez ?"

Comment: On peut aussi considérer l'anglais « STOP » comme un raccourci de « This is a [STOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_sign) sign ».

Comment: Oui mais on ne le fait pas. :-)

Comment: Justement, j'ai plutôt l'impression que si. En français en tous cas, il est courant de dire _un stop_, par exemple dans _Mais enfin monsieur, vous n'aviez pas vu le stop ?_ Cela dit, je crois qu'il ne faut pas chercher beaucoup plus loin qu'une simple volonté d'utiliser un mot court, sachant qu'il doit en plus avoir une hauteur minimum.

Comment: Je ne sais pas par quel bout prendre la question.  Qu'est-ce que ça veut dire « correct » pour un mot isolé ? Le fait que ce ne soit pas un verbe à l'impératif est-il réellement pertinent (on a bien des panneaux hôpital et travaux) ? Si j'avais eu à choisir un autre mot que « stop », j'aurais effectivement pris « halte » plutôt qu'« arrêt ».

Comment: Le bout est d'établir le sens des panneaux *STOP*, et si les panneaux québecois retiennent ce sens.

Comment: Les panneaux sont quelque chose d'essentiellement conventionnel : le seul est celui qu'on leur donne. Si je ne m'abuse, stop est le seul panneau hexagonal, donc même des conventions établies pour les autres pourraient ne pas s'appliquer, et de plus un des rares panneaux (qui ne soit pas un panneau d'orientation) avec du texte. Difficile de dire qu'il ne respecte pas les conventions habituelles, il n'y en a pas.

Comment: Hexagonal ? En voilà un qui a vécu en France trop longtemps :-)

Comment: Depuis suffisamment peu de temps pour savoir que le panneau B5 est hexagonal en Belgique aussi.  Et puis, c'est quand que tu viens me rejoindre en France sans te déplacer ?

Comment: @Un Ils semblent d'être des octogones en France, comme dans la reste du monde: http://www.ilankelman.org/stopsigns/france.jpg

Comment: Je me cache. :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Je pense que la signification de « STOP » sur les panneaux a évolué avec le temps. Si on peut supposer qu'à l'[origine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_sign#History) (en 1915) il était voulu comme un ordre, le fait que le mot a été utilisé de [plus en plus](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=stop%20sign&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) pour dénommer le panneau lui-même (« stop sign ») a certainement contribué a dénaturer la valeur impérative du mot.

Dès lors, lorsqu'il a fallu traduire ce panneau au Québec, la signification de *stop* en tant que substantif était sans doute suffisament établie que pour que la traduction par un autre substantif soit logique. De toutes façons, on peut aussi supposer que l'anglais n'était pas particulièrement vu comme un modèle à cette époque. (Voir aussi les panneaux [vandalisés](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charte_de_la_langue_fran%C3%A7aise))

L'aspect visuel d'un mot court n'est sans doute pas non plus à négliger ; en considérant que la hauteur du mot est fixée, « ARRÊTEZ » serait sans doute trop tassé que pour être lisible.

Comment: La hauteur, ou tu veux dire "les dimensions"?

Comment: _la hauteur du mot est au moins égale au tiers de la hauteur du panneau_ — https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/Panneau_stop#Le_mod.C3.A8le_octogonal

Comment: @Joubarc: Vous avez rédigé : La signification de *stop* en tant que substantif était sans doute suffisament établie **que** pour que la traduction par un autre substantif soit logique. Pourquoi le **que** avant [ pour que ] ? Est-il un doublon ?

Comment: Non, il est voulu, mais je ne suis pas assez sûr des règles concernées que pour expliquer ce qu'il représente. Le sujet mérite une question à part entière, cela dit - je te laisse le soin de la poser.

Answer (score 6):

S'agissant de « s'arrêter » plutôt que d'« arrêter », la tournure impérative adéquate serait « arrêtez-vous ». Un peu long, non ? D'ailleurs, vu l'importance du panneau en question, mieux vaut s'assurer qu'un maximum de gens (même étrangers) le comprennent ; et cela a sûrement pesé en faveur de l'adoption du mot « stop ».

Je fais aussi remarquer qu'on voit souvent des formulations du type « ne pas jeter… », plutôt que « ne jetez pas… » sur des panneaux et écriteaux divers. En fait, l'impératif n'est pas vraiment le mode adéquat pour énoncer des règles, et c'est peut-être pour cela qu'il n'a pas été choisi pour les panneaux de signalisation.

Comment: _Veuillez vous arrêter, s'il-vous-plait_

Answer (score 1):

Trois choses pour compléter:

Les "stops" canadiens (en dans toute l'Amérique du Nord) fonctionnent différemment qu'en Europe. La plupart du temps toutes les rues menant à l'intersection ont un Stop, chaque conducteur marque un temps d'arrêt et repart. Le premier arrivé est celui qui a le droit de repartir en premier. C'est donc différent du stop européen où on reste immobile tant que la voie n'est pas libre. Donc en ce sens le mot "Arrêt" est plus juste.

Dans les "réserves indiennes" le panneau est écrit en langue amérindienne, heureusement qu'il a sa forme si spécifique pour qu'on puisse le reconnaître!

Preuve que c'est un débat linguistique qui dépasse de loin le code de la route: il y a même des panneaux bilingues qui portent l'inscription dans les 2 langues: "Arrêt / Stop", des fois qu'on ne comprenne pas...

Comment: Au Québec, pour plus de précisions voir les art. 360, 368, 369, 370 du [_Code de la sécurité routière_](http://legisquebec.gouv.qc.ca/fr/ShowDoc/cs/C-24.2) ; au passage on notera que dans la loi le conducteur a l'obligation d'_immobiliser_ son véhicule dans ces situations. _S'arrêter_ est ce qu'il ne doit pas omettre de faire suite à un accident ou ce que fait un conducteur d'autobus d'écoliers quand il les fait monter à bord...

Answer (score 0):

Une proposition d'indépendance avait été proposée par le ministre du Québec et celui-ci avait retiré le mot *stop* qui était à une certaine époque jumelé au mot *arrêt* sur le même poteau de signalisation.

Answer (score -1):

Pour la mise en forme du texte. Il y a une erreur syntaxique. Quand un mot est en Majuscule pas besoin de mettre les accents donc **ARRÊT** est déprécié au profit de **ARRET** Cette fois ci sans accent.
Pour le fond je pense que c'est une question de *je préfère le mien* pourquoi pas **STOP** Si on veut rentrer dans le standard international où tout est englishiser. Je crois que mettre dans la langue locale est à encourager et cela est plus explicite pour les ceux qui parlent la
Langue.

Comment: Non, toutes les lettres capitales doivent être accentuées. Voir une des nombreuses sources comme: http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1438