# Quelle est la différence sémantique entre l'infinitif et l'impératif dans le contexte de l'instruction?

Tags: sens, verbes, infinitif, mode-grammatical, impératif

J'ai vu beaucoup d'instructions (par exemple sur l'emballage des produits, les panneaux et les pancartes) en français qui donnent leurs « conseils » en deux formes :

- l'impératif: Partagez la route - Share the road

[image: Un panneau avec l'impératif]

- ou l'infinitif: Concours de pétanque - Ne pas jouer à plat-ventre

[image: Un panneau avec l'infinitif]

(C'est un peu comique, mais également j'ai vu des exemples qui ne sont pas comiques.)

Quelle est la différence sémantique entre les deux formes?

S'il n'y a pas de différence sémantique, est-ce qu'il y a une autre sorte de différence? J'essaie de trouver la raison pour laquelle cette dualité existe.

Comment: Lié : http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1227/les-panneaux-de-signalisation-arret-au-quebec-sont-ils-corrects

Answer (score 9, accepted):

L'infinitif est la forme qui convient le mieux pour l'énonciation de règles ou d'instructions. En particulier il n'est utilisé qu'à l'écrit¹. Exemples typiques :

- Instructions dans la notice d'utilisation d'un appareil
- Instructions dans une recette de cuisine
- Une liste de choses à faire ou ne pas faire dans un mémo
- Interdictions dans un règlement ou sur tout autre document

L'impératif est le mode de l'injonction, avec un sens large. Il est utilisé pour donner des ordres, demander l'application d'une règle ou l'exécution d'une instruction, mais aussi pour formuler des conseils ou autres invitations diverses².

Parfois les deux modes sont possibles. En l’occurrence, sur le deuxième panneau, « *ne jouez pas à plat ventre* » aurait une touche humaine que « *ne pas jouer à plat ventre* » n'a pas. Formuler cela en tant que règle renforce l'effet comique.
En revanche, dans le cas du premier panneau « *partager la route* », resterait probablement incompris. Ce n'est pas une règle ou une instruction, car ça n'a de toute façon pas de sens précis, c'est plutôt une demande, une requête ou un souhait.

—
<sup>1. Enfin c'est possible de l'utiliser à l'oral dans certains cas, mais pour de [toutes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposition_infinitive) autres [raisons](http://www.lemonde.fr/culture/video/2013/09/12/mylene-farmer-en-60-secondes_3476317_3246.html).</sup>
<sup>2. Plus d'exemples sur la page [Impératif](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imp%C3%A9ratif_%28grammaire%29) de Wikipédia.</sup>

Comment: @StéphanieGimenez Merci beaucoup.  Votre réponse est très informative et les exemples sont très clairs.

Answer (score 1):

D'après les (excellentes) photos :

- L'impératif est un ordre donné que l'on doit respecter.
- Le présent indique qu'il n'est pas accepté d'avoir certaines pratiques dans certaines circonstances.

La différence se situe dans la direction de l'obligation :

- impératif : quoique vous fassiez, vous devez *faire ainsi*, vous recevez un ordre.
- infinitif : bien que vous êtes capable de le faire, *dans ce cas précis*, vous vous abstenez, de vous-même.

Comment: Permets-moi de douter du fait que tout impératif soit un ordre. (Non, ceci n'est pas un ordre !)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Comme nous sommes dans un cadre réglementaire : "Terme de grammaire. Le mode des verbes qui exprime commandement, exhortation, défense. Un verbe à l'impératif." (Le Littré) Cela relève du domaine où l'on doit obéir, obtempérer sinon à un ordre du moins à une exhortation sous peine de sanctions annoncées ou déjà connues. J'ai répondu surtout à la dernière phrase de la question, en proposant une autre approche pour décoder les pancartes.