# Verbes en « -er » ou « -ez », quel est le sens des phrases ?

Tags: sens, verbes, conjugaison, infinitif, impératif

Dans de nombreuses phrases ou groupes de mots on peut écrire le verbe soit au présent avec « vous » (ez) soit à l'infinitif (er)

Par exemple

> Marcher droit

Ou

> Marchez droit

---

De même, dans un jeu j'ai remarqué

> Surveiller vos angles peut vous permettre de gagner !

Mais ne peut-on pas le remplacer par

> Surveillez vos angles peut vous permettre de gagner !

---

Dans la phrase précédente « C'est « vous » qui devez surveiller les angles » ne serait pas mieux que « Surveillez vos angles » ?

Je me pose souvent la question suivante quand j'écris « ez »/« er » ; l'un est-il plus correct que l'autre ou bien est-ce que les deux peuvent être employés?

Comment: Question liée : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7616/quelle-est-la-diff%c3%a9rence-s%c3%a9mantique-entre-linfinitif-et-limp%c3%a9ratif-dans-le-con

Comment: Merci beaucoup, je n'avais pas vu ce topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'infinitif ne s'oppose pas tant au présent qu'à l'impératif.

Utiliser l'infinitif peut être utilisé pour indiquer ce qui doit être fait sans donner d'ordre.

L'impératif, comme son nom l'indique, est une demande *impérieuse*, un ordre.

Quand on commence à utiliser l'infinitif pour donner des conseils, il faut continuer à le faire dans la suite de la phrase.

On peut en revanche dire :

> Surveillez vos angles et gagnez peut-être grâce à ça !
>
> Surveillez vos angles, ça peut vous permettre de gagner.

***Marcher droit*** et ***marchez droit*** sont tous deux corrects.

La première forme est une recommandation, une indication impersonnelle et intemporelle alors que la deuxième est un ordre direct donné au(x) destinataire(s).

Answer (score 0):

Non, on ne peut pas le remplacer par « Surveillez vos angles peut vous permettre de gagner ! » parce qu'une forme verbale conjuguée doit avoir un sujet (sauf si le mode est l'impératif) et il n'y a pas de sujet dans la proposition « Surveillez vos angles »  ; cela fait de cette proposition une phrase dont le verbe est à l'impératif et en tant que telle elle ne peut pas entrer dans une construction de phrase comme élément autre que proposition principale ;

> Déplacez ces voitures !
>   Déplacez ces voitures, que la police puisse garer ses véhicules !

Donc la seule possibilité est celle de l'infinitif ;  « Surveiller vos angles » est le sujet de la proposition indépendante « Surveiller vos angles peut vous permettre de gagner ! ». Remarquer qu'il ne s'agit pas là d'un infinitif à valeur d'impératif, il n'est question d'aucune injonction. La proposition infinitive a valeur de groupe nominal : « La surveillance de vos angles peut vous permettre de gagner ! »